# Checking if the current iterating element is the last one?

Tags: javascript

I'm iterating through some files:

```
  files.forEach((file) => {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + `/${input}/` + file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      let result = `${data}\n`

      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }

      fs.appendFile("book.txt", result, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          console.log(result)
        }
      })
    })
  })
```

What I want to do is now something like:

```
// If this is the last file:
  let result = `${data}`

// else:
  let result = `${data}\n`
```

Is there any way so I can check if the current iterating element is the last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you pass to [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) will be called with the current item's index in the second argument. You can compare that index with the array's length and write:

```
files.forEach((file, index) => {
    if (index == files.length - 1) {
        // This is the last file...
    }

    // [...]

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use promises and [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
var promisify = require("promisify-node");
var fs = promisify("fs");
Promise.all(files.map((file) => {
  return fs.readFile(__dirname + `/${input}/` + file, 'utf8')
})).then((data) => {
  var result = data.join('\n')
  return fs.appendFile("book.txt", result);
}).then((result) => {
  console.log(result)
}, (err) => { 
  console.log(err) 
});
```